# python multiprocessing.Queue.get() prints None at unwanted moments

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, ipc, python-multithreading

I have a piece of python code that listens for messages sent by a child process. The message can either be a normal string that is printed directly to a console window, or a tuple with an exception object and traceback ouput that is to be processed somewhere else in the program. The multiprocessing.Queue implementation is used for inter-process communication. The queue object is referenced by self.channel.

```
while self.exp_process.is_alive() or not self.channel.empty():
    # Make sure Qt interface stays responsive, gets redrawn, etc.
    QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

    # Check if messages are pending to be processed
    # Sleep otherwise
    if not self.channel.empty():

        # Encapsulated by print statements for debugging of None print
        print "Retrieving message"
        msg = self.channel.get(False)
        print "Message received"

        # Directly print received strings                                   
        if type(msg) in [str, unicode]:
            sys.stdout.write(msg)

        # Errors arrive as a tuple with (Error object, traceback)
        elif type(msg) == tuple and isinstance(msg[0], Exception):                                                          
            return msg
        else:
            sys.stderr.write(u"Illegal message type received from child process")
    else:
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

When a msg is a tuple (containing error info from the child process), the

```
msg = self.channel.get(False)
```

appears to print None, as the output in the console is

```
Retrieving message
None
Message received
```

After this, the tuple contained by msg is processed as it should, indicating that the correct info was received. It seems that None is printed somewhere inside the Queue.get() function, when receiving a tuple.
Is there anyway to suppress its output, or fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have some function that prints to `stdout`, and you'd like to suppress the output, you can temporarily redefine `sys.stdout`. Here's an example:

```
def f(text):
    print(text)

import sys
import StringIO

saved = sys.stdout                # Save.
sys.stdout = StringIO.StringIO()  # Redefine.
f('first')                        # Will not print.
sys.stdout = saved                # Recover.
f('second')                       # Will print.
```

Output is:

```
second
```

And in case you're not sure whether the function prints to `stdout` or `stderr`, you can suppress both:

```
import sys
from StringIO import StringIO

saved = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
sys.stdout, sys.stderr = StringIO(), StringIO()
f('first')
sys.stdout, sys.stderr = saved
f('second')
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: This does the trick, thanks. Isn't this resource expensive though? I made sure at least that the StringIO object is created once before the loop starts and then just referenced inside the loop. Is the fact that Queue.get() prints None not a serious bug in this Python library? Although your solution is simple and effective, it appears to be an unnecessary ugly hack to me.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Seeing how it's a GUI application, I'm guessing you won't notice drain on your system resources (I'd be more concerned about finding how *not*  to use ``time.sleep()`` in your code.) Serious bug in your library? Probably. My solution a hack? Definitely. Ugly? You mean as opposed to debugging and fixing your ``multiprocessing`` module C code...?

Comment: I used the time.sleep to pause the process for a second and not let it check for messages in the channel constantly, which I thought was the right way to do this, but I may be wrong. Debugging the Python C code is not really an option for me, so this approach will do. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of ``time.sleep(0.1)``, you're better off using get() with a blocking timeout: ``self.channel.get(True, 0.1)`` plus a slight redesign of the loop.